# Get current screen name of drawer navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation for my react native app. Currently, my drawer have 5 menus. Let's assume there are Home screen, ScreenA, ScreenB, Screen,C, and ScreenD.

I want a behaviour like this

- If user press back button on Android on Home Screen, the screen will show pop up
- If user press back button on Android on other screen except Home Screen, the screen will navigate to Home Screen.

I also use Redux Integration and did all the setup as described in React Navigation's documentation.

Need your help guys. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this?